# SQL: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to execute a simple SQL query as below

```
select * from  VW_TRAVEL vw where vw.TRAVEL_ID = '47132'
```

For which i get the below exception.

```
ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484
01854. 00000 -  "julian date must be between 1 and 5373484"
*Cause:    An invalid Julian date was entered.
*Action:   Enter a valid Julian date between 1 and 5373484.
```

Please guide.

Comment: Seems you have an invalid value on that row, or your date configurations are wrong, you can start from here.

Comment: VW_TRAVEL is a view? How it is defined?

Comment: The problem is in the definition of the view, not in your query.  Hence there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: i will paste the defination of my view

Answer (score 1):

Julian day numbers after 5373484 correspond to dates after 9999-12-31. You could be running into an integrity check, or a limitation of the database.